# Multidimensional Newton-Raphson

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

I have a system of $n$ rational functions of degree $d$, $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ in variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, i.e. $\forall i, f_i = p_i/q_i$ where $p_i, q_i$ are multivariate polynomials of degree at most $d$. I would like to find a good approximation of a real root of this system (if it exists). The most popular method seems to be the multidimensional Newton iteration. However, it is known that Newton iteration has bad global convergence. I have two questions:

1. Is there a method that has super-linear convergence rate, and has good global convergence? I'd be interested even in methods even in the univariate setting.
2. Does the fact that my system is made up of rational functions help/hinder Newton iteration? I understand that $f_i$'s have the same roots as $p_i$, but since the multidimensional version needs the evaluation of a Jacobian, does this cause problems?

I'm interested in algorithms with a provable guarantee.

Cross posted on math.SE and did not get any pointers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624378/multivariate-newton-raphson

Comment: What do you mean with "I'm interested only in the theory"? That you just need to know "this can be done in O(whatever)"? Are you interested in bit complexity, or flops complexity? Do you need all roots in the complex plane? Only the real ones? Only one root?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I meant, I want just one real root. I'll edit this question to make it clear. I am more interested in algorithms with a provable guarantee for both global convergence and rate of convergence -- if there are any.